# Auto logout specific users in Django

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-sessions

I know that we can implement auto logout with  `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` variable, but this method apply to all users.
My question is:

***What is the best practice for implement auto logout system for specific users such as admin's or super admin's?***

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is admin/super admin . If so, simply set  `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` only for that user

Comment: How? @farhan-syedian